# Paint JS changing color onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm trying to make Paint in JS here's the code.
I want to change color of the trail from black to red by clicking on div "red" for example,and I'm out of ideas (without jQuery).

```js
let active = false;
const draw = function(e) {
  if (active == false) {
    return;
  }

  const x = e.clientX;
  const y = e.clientY;
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.top = y + "px";
  div.style.left = x + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

const drawActive = function() {
  active = !active
}

function changeColor() {
  //div.classList.add("mainColor");
}

document.getElementById("red").onclick = changeColor;
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", drawActive);
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", drawActive);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#containter {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
}

div {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
}

#red {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 18%;
}

.blue {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.yellow {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 18%;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.green {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 6%;
}

.first {
  background-color: red !important;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.mainColor {
  background-color: red !important;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Paint</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="containter">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to make it with setAttribute but I had some errors.
I don't know which details should I give.
I don't know which details should I give.´

**@Edit** *from review*: removed 6 more repetitions...

Answer (score 0):

I used the `querySelectorAll` to find all div and added condition

```
if (!document.getElementById("containter").contains(item))
```

to except content within div id `container`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function (item) {
if (!document.getElementById("containter").contains(item))
    item.setAttribute('class', 'mainColor');
})
```

```js
let active = false;
const draw = function(e) {
  if (active == false || document.getElementById("containter").contains(e.target)) {
    return;
  }
  const x = e.clientX;
  const y = e.clientY;
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.style.top = y + "px";
  div.style.left = x + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
const drawActive = function() {
  active = !active
}

function changeColor() {
  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(item) {
    if (!document.getElementById("containter").contains(item))
      item.setAttribute('class', 'mainColor');
  })
}
document.getElementById("red").onclick = changeColor;
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", drawActive);
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", drawActive);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#containter {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
}

div {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
}

#red {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 18%;
}

.blue {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.yellow {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 18%;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.green {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-top: 6%;
}

.first {
  background-color: red !important;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.mainColor {
  background-color: red !important;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Paint</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="containter">
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```